# How to capture shell WScript Shell output from Excel VBA without using cmd?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, wscript.shell

I have used the various posts similar to this and come up with the following, but not sure why this doesn't work for me. I have a UserForm wherein I am trying to run a script and capture the output, including any errors. However, the console window quickly disappears as soon as I run this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

command = "python ""C:\test1.py --arg1=ABC"" > ""C:\logs\test.log"""
wsh.Run command, windowStyle, waitOnReturn

End Sub
```

The script runs just fine by itself until I add the redirection ('>'). My python script needs to be launched with 'python' keyword preceded in the command as shown above and so I cannot use 'cmd /c'. Is it possible to capture the output without using 'cmd /c' and while using wsh.Run (preferably) instead of wsh.Exec?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use Shell "cmd /c <python_path>\python.exe <python_path>\test1.py --arg1=ABC > C:\logs\test.log"?

Comment: I am using anaconda so want to avoid using/launching the default windows cmd.

Comment: First try command = "python C:\test1.py --arg1=ABC" and see if it works.  If it does, try command = "python C:\test1.py --arg1=ABC > C:\logs\test.log".  I don't have anaconda and couldn't test it out.

Comment: the first command (without redirection to log file) works. The 2nd does not work. Is that because '>' can be used with 'cmd /c' only? With 'cmd /c', the '>' works but the performance is bad for some reason. Without 'cmd /c', the anaconda prompt takes effect and command run is much faster but '>' redirection to log file does not work.

Comment: The '>' can be used without cmd /c.  Have you tried to type the commend on a CMD window and it works?  Just want to make sure the target path / file is accessible.

Comment: Just retested: The command "python C:\test1.py --arg1=ABC > C:\logs\test.log"  works fine from CMD window but not from within the VBA when used with wsh like this: command = "python C:\test1.py --arg1=ABC > C:\logs\test.log" and then wsh.Run

Comment: I assume you run the command line from CMD window with the default C:\ path (i.e.it looks like: C:\> "python C:\test1.py --arg1=ABC > C:\logs\test.log).  I don't have any more suggestion at the moment as It might have something to do with how anaconda call up python script for piping output.  Also just curious if you tried ">>" instead of ">"